# Simple posts to Facebook and Twitter iOS 5 & 6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, twitter

I'm currently implementing a simple button that posts to social networking sites (giving my app a little exposure, you know the drill). However, I'm a little confused by all this social networking stuff. On one hand I know iOS 6 has a really nice framework for FB and Twitter (`Social.framework`) but for iOS 5 it's a little different. iOS 6, I think I've got figured... I find it a little weirder when we go into iOS 5 however. From what I understand Twitter was already integrated into iOS 5 and can be accessed using the `Twitter.framework` and `Account.framework` frameworks. What I don't get is in order to support both 5 & 6 for Twitter do I have to use `Social.framework`, `Twitter.framework` and `Account.framework` to support everything? I.e. two different methods depending on iOS version. Or, if I use the latest SDK will iOS 5 twitter work with `Social.framework`? That Twitter covered.

Now for Facebook, how do I go about posting in iOS 5? I'm pretty sure `Social.framework` won't work in iOS 5, even if I build the app with latest SDK. Therefore I think it's inevitable that I'll have to have two different methods which run depending on the iOS version installed. Is that correct? If so, how do I go about integrating FB into iOS 5? Do I have to use the SDKs provided by Facebook?

So to summarise my questions if all that was a little wordy.

1) Can I incorporate Twitter-posting into my app using only `Social.framework` for both iOS 5 & 6, or do I have to do one method using `Social.framework` (for iOS 6) and then another method using `Twitter.framework` and `Account.framework` (iOS 5)?

2) I can use `Social.framework` for Facebook in iOS 6, but can't for iOS 5, therefore, I have to do two separate methods, one with `Social.framework` (iOS 6) and then one with the FB SDK (iOS 5), correct?

Thanks in advance,
 Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) `Social.Framework` is available only on iOS6+ so you have to split between the two frameworks (or you can use only `Twitter.Framework` even though some methods have been deprecated on iOS6)

2) You can use the Facebook SDK both on iOS5 and iOS6 (latest version for iOS at the time i write this answer is [3.5](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.5)). The Facebook SDK already takes care of using the user's Facebook account on iOS6 or relying on the Facebook app on iOS5 or iOS6 when the account is not already configured in the phone

Comment: Thank you. So I'm going to have to use the Twitter.framework for iOS 5  (& optionally 6) and the FB SDK 3.5 for iOS 5 (& optionally 6) and then the Social.framework for FB and Twitter in iOS 6. Looks like I can do this using just two frameworks!! Is the Twitter.framework already in the the SDK or am I going to have to download it like the FB SDK?

Comment: If i had to choose, i would probably use the Facebook SDK as the only way to share on Facebook (no point imho in using `Social.framework` if you still have to support iOS5). For Twitter i would probably use only the `Twitter.framework` on both iOS5 & iOS6 until i am ok to change my deployment target to iOS6+. In that case, i would switch to the `Social.framework` completely.